# MySQL: Adding columns where one has NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT (contract_value + amendment_value) AS total_value
FROM contracts
ORDER BY total_value DESC
```

When I run it, the result for each row is `NULL`.  Why is that so?

Each row has either a `contract_value` or an `amendment_value`, but not both.  Where there is no value, it is NULL.  Could that be the problem?  (I could not find anything in the documentation to suggest it).  If so, how do I get around it?

Comment: `COALESCE(contract_value, amendment_value)` will return whichever is non-NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(contract_value, amendment_value) AS total_value
FROM contracts
ORDER BY total_value DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `coalesce()` - all are showing null because any of your two value is null - with null value any calculation will return as null, so in this case, you've to replace null with 0

```
SELECT coalesce(contract_value,0) + coalesce(amendment_value,0) AS total_value
FROM contracts
ORDER BY total_value DESC
```